# botocore.exceptions.SSLError (CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED) inside a docker container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, boto3, botocore

I have been trying for quite some time to figure out what is going wrong when I am making an API call to my AWS account using boto3 library inside a Docker container. The error I see is:

```
docker run --rm -ti -v ${HOME}/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials:ro boto3_test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 411, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 428, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 472, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1125)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 314, in send
    urllib_response = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 507, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 411, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 428, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 472, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1125)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/src/main.py", line 51, in <module>
    print(dynamodb_ss.get_all_records())
  File "/src/main.py", line 25, in get_all_records
    response = self.table.scan()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 662, in _make_api_call
    http, parsed_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 682, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 136, in _send_request
    while self._needs_retry(attempts, operation_model, request_dict,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 253, in _needs_retry
    responses = self._event_emitter.emit(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 250, in __call__
    should_retry = self._should_retry(attempt_number, response,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 316, in __call__
    checker_response = checker(attempt_number, response,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 222, in __call__
    return self._check_caught_exception(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 200, in _do_get_response
    http_response = self._send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 269, in _send
    return self.http_session.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 341, in send
    raise SSLError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1125)
```

My Dockerfile contains the following:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY /src/ /src/

RUN chmod +x /src/main.py

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "/src/main.py"]
```

Here is my `requirements.txt` file:

```
awscli==1.19.50
boto3==1.17.50
botocore==1.20.50
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi==1.14.5
colorama==0.4.3
cryptography==3.4.7
docutils==0.15.2
jmespath==0.10.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pycparser==2.20
pyOpenSSL==20.0.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
PyYAML==5.4.1
rsa==4.7.2
s3transfer==0.3.6
six==1.15.0
urllib3==1.26.4
```

Essentially I'm just trying to retrieve a list of records in DynamoDB. This script works fine locally, but fails inside a Docker container.

Do I have to configure SSL certs? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Brian

EDIT: here is the Python code

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def gen_session_obj(profile_name='dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2'):
    return boto3.Session(profile_name=profile_name, region_name=region_name)


def gen_client(session, service):
    client = session.resource(service)
    return client


class DynamoDbStateStore:

    def __init__(self, dynamo_db_resource, table):
        self.dynamodb_session = dynamo_db_resource
        self.table = self.dynamodb_session.Table(table)

    def get_all_records(self, project_expression=''):
        try:
            if project_expression:
                response = self.table.scan(ProjectionExpression=project_expression)
            else:
                response = self.table.scan()
            data = response.get('Items')

            while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
                if project_expression:
                    response = self.table.scan(
                        ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'],
                        ProjectionExpression=project_expression
                    )
                else:
                    response = self.table.scan(
                        ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey']
                    )
                data.extend(response['Items'])
        except ClientError as e:
            print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
            raise
        return data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    session = gen_session_obj()
    dynamodb_client = gen_client(session, 'dynamodb')

    dynamodb_ss = DynamoDbStateStore(dynamodb_client, 'user_mgr_audit_log')
    print(dynamodb_ss.get_all_records())
```

Comment: Can you show example python code that leads to error?

Comment: @Marcin sure. I updated the original post

Comment: I am able to get by the SSL verification failure by setting `verify=False`, but I don't think that is a good solution. I'm wondering if I have to set this env var in the container `AWS_CA_BUNDLE`?

Comment: This is rather OS level issue I think. But `python:3.8-slim` is not that old (Debian 10), and it should have up to date root certificates. If its possible maybe you can try with other base image?

Comment: I tried using just `python:3.8` and it still failed.

Comment: Very strange. Is there any chance for you to try from other computer? E.g. ec2 instance with docker?

Comment: I tried a simple docker container to make an HTTPS request on my Windows 10 computer and it worked fine. Still get the SSL error on my Mac, but I am also on my work corporate network which may have something to do with the SSL error.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out. I am also having the same issue with boto3/awscli inside of containers. I can run the same code locally on my mac and it works.

Comment: No not yet. I had a co-worker pull the docker image off the branch I'm working on and SSL connections worked fine for him. If I figure it out I will share an update here.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the ssl layer.
Before your code add

```
import ssl

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the input. Unfortunately the request still failed with the same error.